# Hibernate, display join left results in Spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm learning Spring and Hibernate and i have small but quite important problem.

I want to get data from database:

```
 Query query = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM pool a LEFT JOIN pool_question b on a.id = b.poolid");
```

and then sent results as list to jsp file from my controller

```
model.addAttribute("pools", pool);
```

My database is quite simple:

pool is:

```
id  name    slug    date_create deactivation_date   creator_id  active
```

and poolquestion is

```
id  poolid  answer  order   question
```

The problem is, that when i'm trying to make a loop in jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${pools}" var="pool">
        <td><c:out value="${pool.name}" /></td>
</c:forEach>
```

tomcat displays me error.

When i check my query in phpmyadmin the result is ok.

The trick is, that when i do query like this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Pool");
```

The results in jsp are displayed properly.

Could enyone help me how to display result of this query in jsp?

My Pool.java is:

```
    package com.pool.app.domain;

// Generated 2011-12-20 12:45:22 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

/**
 * Pool generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "pool", catalog = "pool")
public class Pool implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String slug;
    private Date dateCreate;
    private Date deactivationDate;
    private int creatorId;
    private int active;
    private Set<PoolQuestion> poolQuestions = new HashSet<PoolQuestion>(0);

    public Pool() {
    }

    public Pool(String name, String slug, Date dateCreate,
            Date deactivationDate, int creatorId, int active) {
        this.name = name;
        this.slug = slug;
        this.dateCreate = dateCreate;
        this.deactivationDate = deactivationDate;
        this.creatorId = creatorId;
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Pool(String name, String slug, Date dateCreate,
            Date deactivationDate, int creatorId, int active,
            Set<PoolQuestion> poolQuestions) {
        this.name = name;
        this.slug = slug;
        this.dateCreate = dateCreate;
        this.deactivationDate = deactivationDate;
        this.creatorId = creatorId;
        this.active = active;
        this.poolQuestions = poolQuestions;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 200)
    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "slug", nullable = false, length = 200)
    public String getSlug() {
        return this.slug;
    }

    public void setSlug(String slug) {
        this.slug = slug;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "date_create", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getDateCreate() {
        return this.dateCreate;
    }

    public void setDateCreate(Date dateCreate) {
        this.dateCreate = dateCreate;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "deactivation_date", nullable = false, length = 19)
    public Date getDeactivationDate() {
        return this.deactivationDate;
    }

    public void setDeactivationDate(Date deactivationDate) {
        this.deactivationDate = deactivationDate;
    }

    @Column(name = "creator_id", nullable = false)
    public int getCreatorId() {
        return this.creatorId;
    }

    public void setCreatorId(int creatorId) {
        this.creatorId = creatorId;
    }

    @Column(name = "active", nullable = false)
    public int getActive() {
        return this.active;
    }

    public void setActive(int active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "pool")
    public Set<PoolQuestion> getPoolQuestions() {
        return this.poolQuestions;
    }

    public void setPoolQuestions(Set<PoolQuestion> poolQuestions) {
        this.poolQuestions = poolQuestions;
    }

}
```

and PoolQuestion.java is:

```
    package com.pool.app.domain;

// Generated 2011-12-20 12:45:22 by Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

/**
 * PoolQuestion generated by hbm2java
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "pool_question", catalog = "pool")
public class PoolQuestion implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private Pool pool;
    private String answer;
    private int order;
    private String question;

    public PoolQuestion() {
    }

    public PoolQuestion(Pool pool, String answer, int order) {
        this.pool = pool;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.order = order;
    }

    public PoolQuestion(Pool pool, String answer, int order, String question) {
        this.pool = pool;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.order = order;
        this.question = question;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "poolid", nullable = false)
    public Pool getPool() {
        return this.pool;
    }

    public void setPool(Pool pool) {
        this.pool = pool;
    }

    @Column(name = "answer", nullable = false, length = 500)
    public String getAnswer() {
        return this.answer;
    }

    public void setAnswer(String answer) {
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    @Column(name = "order", nullable = false)
    public int getOrder() {
        return this.order;
    }

    public void setOrder(int order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    @Column(name = "question", length = 500)
    public String getQuestion() {
        return this.question;
    }

    public void setQuestion(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

}
```

And the main question - how the HQL query should looks, becouse query like this:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("From Pool as p left join fetch p.id as s");
```

doesn't works for me.

Comment: OK, i made id - Query query = session.createQuery("From Pool as p left join fetch p.poolQuestions as s");

Answer (score 0):

Without the exception it's hard to know exactly what's going wrong. However, have a read of:

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html

I think you're problem is that you're using `createSQLQuery` instead of `createQuery`. Ie you're using standard SQL instead of HQL. To get you started, try changing your query to:

`SELECT a.* FROM pool a LEFT JOIN ...`

and make a call to `.addEntity(Pool.class)`, ie `session.createSQLQuery("<use above SQL>").addEntity(Pool.class);`

Good luck.

Comment: Can you help me with HQL Query? How i should create query. I was reading tutorials and i created something like this:             Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Pool as pool left join fetch pool.id children");
But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

When using Hibernate You don't usually want to use native SQL but rather [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html).
If you are using native query `createSQLQuery` then you have to specify explicitly How should be values mapped to your [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) or specify scalars - see hibernate documentation.

And **why are you using this query in the first place?** Can't you obtain the poolquestion values from some [association mapping](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/associations.html) of Pool class? That's the whole point of Hibernate.

Let me be more clear.
First forget the join in query. You don't need it. You want POJO instances no some crazy result set of outer join.

1. Query all `Pool` data as you did `Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Pool");`
2. Get list containing Pool instances representing your data `List<Pool> pools = (List<Pool>) query.list();`
3. **Now you have it.** All associated data are obtained by Hibernate lazily when you ask for them -  `pool.getPoolQuestions();`

Comment: I have mapped MySQL classes and i was trying to build my query with HQL, but this doesn't work for me. I was reading a lot of tutorials and examples, but I cant build correct HQL Query. That's why i started to build query with Native query.

Comment: Can you help me with HQL Query? How i should create query. I was reading tutorials and i created something like this: Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Pool as pool left join fetch pool.id children"); But it doesn't work.

Comment: i've edited my post and i've added POJO classes - if you could take a look on it...

Answer (score 0):

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Pool");
```

Is an HQL query, it will give you a list of Objects (Pool), so there is no problem to use :

```
<c:forEach items="${pools}" var="pool">
        <td><c:out value="${pool.name}" /></td>
</c:forEach>
```

when you use an SQL query, it's different, you will not get a list of objects (you have to add some code and transformations to get a list of pools).

Here an example :

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public List<Pool> findPools()
{
    final String query = "select a.id as idAlias, a.name as nameAlias from pool a ....";
    List<Pool> list = (List<Pool>) getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback()
    {
        public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException
        {
            SQLQuery sqlQuery = session.createSQLQuery(query);
            return prepareQueryFind(sqlQuery).list();
        }
    });
    return list;
}
```

Here i suppose you have a constructor like :

```
public Pool(Integer id, String name);
/** Getters and Setters **/
```

if you are using Hibernate version >= 3.2

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private Query prepareQueryFind(SQLQuery query)
{
    return query
   .addScalar("idAlias", Hibernate.INTEGER)
   .addScalar("nameAlias", Hibernate.STRING)
   .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Pool.class));
}
```

Now you can call fidpools like this :

```
List<Pool> poolList = poolDao.findPools();
```

Comment: Can you help me with HQL Query? How i should create query. I was reading tutorials and i created something like this: Query query = session.createQuery("FROM Pool as pool left join fetch pool.id children"); But it doesn't work.

Comment: Before writing hql query, you must configure jdbc, write the mapping schema (mapping the pojo and tables), then you write the dao classes

you can read this tutorial : http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/maven-hibernate-annonation-mysql-example/

if you want give me your email, i will send you a simple example done with Maven, Spring, Jdbc and Hibernate

Comment: Thank you, but i have everything - jdbc, spring mvc, mapped pojo and tables. I have working Spring MVC application. Only problem that i have is the Join Left HQL querys - they doesn't works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`Query hqlQuery = session.createQuery("from Pool as P left join P.poolQuestion");`

You can look for more [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html).

Some advice:
   If you are using Hibernate and Spring, why you don't use getHibernateTemplate() to get your data from tables?  In this case you can use:

`List<Pool> result = (List<Pool>) getHibernateTemplate().find("from Pool");`

and all you data will be in this *result*.
 For more details you can follow this [example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-hibernate-annotation-mysql-example/).

Please check if I'm right, because I haven't tested/simulated it.